# Retrieving two columns with 'DISTINCT' applied on each column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct

This is a table `books`

> ```
> +--------------+--------------+
> | author_fname | author_lname |
> +--------------+--------------+
> | Dan          | Harris       |
> | Freida       | Harris       |
> | George       | Saunders     |
> +--------------+--------------+
> ```

I am aware that if `DISTINCT` is used as

`SELECT DISTINCT author_fname, author_lname FROM books;`

This will give me the below result because it will give me distinct rows combined by `author_fname` and `author_lname`:

```
+--------------+--------------+
| author_fname | author_lname |
+--------------+--------------+
| Dan          | Harris       |
| Freida       | Harris       |
| George       | Saunders     |
+--------------+--------------+
```

Is there any way to apply `DISTINCT` to each column `author_fname` and `author_lname` like below result so that I only get `Harris` and `Saunders` for `author_lname` other than applying `DISTINCT` to a column-wise?

```
+--------------+--------------+
| author_fname | author_lname |
+--------------+--------------+
| Dan          | Harris       |
| Freida       | Saunders     |
| George       |    sth       |
+--------------+--------------+
```

Comment: Please show the results that you want.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have edited :)

Comment: Which version of MySQL?

Comment: @Nick it says that I am using 5.5.57-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 :)

Comment: It's probably going to be easier to achieve this in your application framework. To do it in MySQL would require a FULL JOIN of the two columns of distinct values using a row number, which is tricky to implement in MySQL 8+ and very hard in versions 5.x What language are you using?

Comment: @Nick Oh, thank you for your advice! I am not using any language yet but just studying SQL :)

Comment: Your result set makes no sense to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want one row per distinct last name, you can use `group by`:

```
select last_name, min(first_name)
from books
group by last_name;
```